# Learn how to write AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am very new to SFMC and I am trying to learn AMP Script but i even don't know that where should I write amp script code??

I want to execute this sample code but i dont know where to write this and view the output??

```
%%[
  var @firstName
  set @firstName = "Test"

  %%= v(@firstName) =%% 
]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampscript is used to add personalization/ back end logic to email, sms and landing pages.

A good place to start learning will be here: [Official Documentation.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/index.htm)

To use your snippet, you would either create an email or a landing page and preview it there.

You would also have to correct it to this:

```
%%[
  var @firstName
  set @firstName = "Test"
]%%

 %%=v(@firstName)=%%
```

This will Print `Test`

Comment: Thanks for your help. If i use above snippet in Mircosite then on clicking on preview button can i see the output of my snippet??

Comment: Yes..this should work for you

Comment: You would also want to read up about syntax especially how to "call" ie. using `%%=v(@firstName)=%%`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really helps. I have another question regarding Ampscript. Could you please look on it?? Link: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192206/read-data-from-data-extension-and-add-into-picklist-value

Comment: On microsite it doesn't work. It's not showing the output of snippet

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your code in SFMC to your question @Puja?

Comment: I have written the same code which display test as output. That code works in landing page but doesn't work in microsite